# how to stop all class function if one class function return false

Tags: php, sendmail

I am creating a mail class. I want to stop all function if one function return false,

call the class

```
<?php
  $mail= new mail();
  $mail->from('abc@gmail.com');
  $mail->to('jhon@gmail.com');
  $mailsend=$mail->send();

  if($mailsend){echo 'mail send';}else{echo 'not send';}
?>
```

the class

```
<?php
  class mail{
    public function from($email){
      /*
       * email validation
       * if not valid return false and stop then send and other functions
       */
    }
    public function to(){

    }
    public function send(){

    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: when returning false from one of the functions, just before the actual return statement, set a flag (ie. $this->disabled = true). Then in all functions the first thing you need to check is: if($this->disabled) { return false; }

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`Exceptions`](http://php.net/exception).

Wrap your code in `try..catch` block and throw an `Exception` when a problem is found.

Like this:

```
class mail {
   public function from($addr) {
       if(not valid addr) throw new Exception("Invalid from address");
   }
   ...
}

try
{
    $mail = new mail();
    $mail->from("invalid email address");
    $mail->to("to@example.com");
    $mail->send();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Email not sent: " . $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

This way, once `from()` has discovered an invalid address, it will throw an exception, and the execution will stop at that point and resume inside `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

combine all into a send function

```
class mail{
    public function send($to,$from){
    //do the mailing 
    if(!emailIsValid())
      return false;
     //and so on
     //if all is fine ..validation etc
     return true;

  }
}
```

then call it like so

```
<?php
  $mail= new mail();
  if($mail->send('abc@gmail.com','jhon@gmail.com')){echo 'mail send';}else{echo 'not   send';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this is to chain your method calls. To do this, each method in your class should return the instance itself except for the last one `send()`. Every method prior to that is merely for setting data and then the `send()` method will trigger a validation.

So your call would look something like...

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->to('abc@gmail.com')
     ->from('xyz@gmail.com')
     ->send();
```

And your class could look like:

```
class Mail {

   protected $to = null;
   protected $from = null;

   public function to($email)
   {
      // You should filter here
      $this->to = $email;

      return $this;
   }

   public function from($email)
   {
      // You should filter here
      $this->from = $email;

      return $this;
   }

   public function send()
   {
      // Validate
      if ($this->validate())
      {
         // Sending logic
      }
      else
      {
        // Return or show error
      }
   }

   public function validate()
   {
      // Verify email values are valid
   }
}
```

Because it is all neatly packaged as a single call chain, you can return an error up the chain or throw an exception as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

make a (private) variable `valid` in your class:

```
 class mail{
  private $valid;
  public function from($email){
    //validation
    $valid = false||true; //the return value
  }
  public function to(){

  }
  public function send(){
    if ($valid) {
      //send mail
      return true
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

It isn't the best way to do it but this way is most similar to your version